# Having class inherit all operators of template type

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators

I created this class so I can have a value of any type which is either fixed or recalculated everytime it is used:

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicValue {
    private:
    std::variant<T, std::function<T()>> getter;

    public:
    DynamicValue(const T& constant) : getter(constant){};
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& function) : getter(function) {}
    DynamicValue(const T* pointer) : DynamicValue([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) : getter(value.getter) {}
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    DynamicValue& operator=(const DynamicValue& value) {
        getter = value.getter;
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() {
        return getter.index() == 0 ? std::get<T>(getter) : std::get<std::function<T()>>(getter)();
    }
};
```

I also wrote the following dummy struct to showcase my issue:

```
struct A {
    int b;
};
```

The problem is, ideally, I'd be able to treat any `DynamicValue<T>` as if it were of type `T`. So if I were to create a new value (`DynamicValue<A> a = A{1};`), I'd be able to do `a.b` and get the attribute `b` of the value calculated by `a`. However, I get the folowing error:

> 'class DynamicValue' has no member named 'b'

You can try a live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bxavvv).

My question is: is there anyway to overcome this issue, or must I accept the `((A) a).b` syntax? I thought about overloading every operator to achieve my goal, but this solution wouldn't work with the `.` operator (and others), which is not overloadable, and might come with its own issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, ideally, I'd be able to treat any `DynamicValue<T>` as if it were of type `T`. So if I were to create a new value (`DynamicValue<A> a = A{1};`), I'd be able to do `a.b` and get the attribute b of the value calculated by `a`.

That would require either `operator.` overloading or delegated inheritance. Both are not available in C++.

I would recomment two models: `operator()` overloading or `operator*`.

Overloading the call operator will make your `DynamicValue` look like a function, whether it contains a function or a value:

```
DynamicValue<A> a = A{1};

auto real_a = a();
std::cout << real_a.b;
```

If you overload the dereference operator, your class would look like a pointer to a value, whether it's a value or a function:

```
DynamicValue<A> a = A{1};

auto real_a = *a;
std::cout << real_a.b;
```

I would be careful with `operator->` since it may induce significant performance degradation if your dynamic value contains a function.

I would completely avoid implicit conversion operators since it comes with a lot of caveat and gotcha. It's a great footgun and must be implemented with caution.